# Read a value from appsettings.json in 1.0.0-rc1-final

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In one of my concrete class. I have the method.

```
public class Call : ICall
{
    ......
    public  Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetHttpResponseMessageFromDeviceAndDataService()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:30151");
        var response =  GetAsyncHttpResponseMessage(client, uri);
        return response;
    }
```

Now I put the url into appsettings.json.

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
       "uri": "http://localhost:30151"
    }
 }
```

And I created a `Startup.cs`

```
 public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

and now I get stuck.

**EDIT**

By the way, I don't have a controller, it is a console application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way to read configuration from appSettings.json is using dependency injection and the built or (or 3rd party) IoC container. All you need is to pass the configuration section to the `Configure` method.

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public int NoRooms { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}

services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("appsettings"));
```

This way you don't have to manually set the values or initialize the `AppSettings` class.

And use it in your service:

```
public class Call : ICall
{
    private readonly AppSettings appSettings;

    public Call(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings) 
    {
        this.appSettings = appSetings.Value;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage>GetHttpResponseMessageFromDeviceAndDataService()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri(appSettings.Uri);
        var response =  GetAsyncHttpResponseMessage(client, uri);
        return response;
    }
}
```

The IoC Container can also be used in a console application, you just got to bootstrap it yourself. The `ServiceCollection` class has no dependencies and can be instantiated normally and when you are done configuring, convert it to an `IServiceProvider` and resolve your main class with it and it would resolve all other dependencies.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build()
            .ReloadOnChanged("appsettings.json");

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("appsettings"));
        services.AddTransient<ICall, Call>();
        // add other services

        // after configuring, build the IoC container
        IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        Program program = provider.GetService<Program>();

        // run the application, in a console application we got to wait synchronously
        program.Wait();
    }

    private readonly ICall callService;
    // your programs main entry point
    public Program(ICall callService) 
    {
        this.callService = callService;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
         HttpResponseMessage result = await call.GetHttpResponseMessageFromDeviceAndDataService();

         // do something with the result
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that there is a `Configure` method? Ex: `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
      // Configure your application pipeline here
    }`. So what class has it?The method is in `AppSettings.cs`?

Comment: `Configure` is a method of `IServiceCollection`, the base of ASP.NET IoC container used for registrations and you add it within `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup` class

Comment: I had `Startup` class now I delete it as I don't have a controller in console application. I don't need it I guess. Is there a way around it? Can you add your entire code?

Comment: There is nothing about controller. Dependency Injection works everywhere and is nothing controller or mvc specific, you just need to consequently use the IoC/DI system

Comment: I know. But do I need Startup class? And how to call it?

Comment: Never tried a pure console application without it being a webserver, but the `Startup` class (and `StartupProduction` etc) is called by ASP.NET (in DNX it's this line of code that does the startup: `public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);`, Not sure yet if there is a equivalent of `WebApplication.Run<T>` for pure non-ASP.NET that do not serve a webservice or web application. Added an example that should work just as it is, but there is probably a better way

Comment: Thank you. I will look at your code. The difficult thing is that my class `Call.ca` is in another project in which there is no Program.cs related directly.

Comment: It will still work if you register all dependencies in your main program that is. IoC/DI happens on application level, all other libraries should be unaware of it

Answer (score 3):

Create a static class

```
public static class AppSettings
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public static T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        if (Configuration == null)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            var configuration = builder.Build();
            Configuration = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        }

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Configuration[key], typeof(T));
    }
}
```

then access the settings anywhere you want like

```
var uri = AppSettings.Get<string>("uri"); 
var rooms = AppSettings.Get<int>("noRooms");
```

appsettings.json example

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "uri": "http://localhost:30151",
        "noRooms":  100
    }
}
```

Comment: I love your answer. I will test it soon. I prefer the more complicated solution such as the json has the second level.(nest)

Comment: Bad solution. Don't use static or singleton classes, this beats the purpose of using IoC Container/DI in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can access data from the IConfigurationRoot as following:

```
Configuration["AppSettings:uri"]
```

Like suggested in the comment I would put the information in a seperate class for that info and pass it into the DI container.

**the class**

```
public class AppSettings {
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}
```

**DI**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(new AppSettings() { Uri = Configuration["AppSettings:uri"] });
    // ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class DemoController
{
    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings) 
    {
       //do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is the variable is in the different class. Should I instantiate the `Startup` class? If so, it has an argument to pass in. Not sure... Please add the entire code.

Comment: You shouldn't create an other instance of the `startup` class. What I suggest is create a new object for the settings and inject it in a controller using DI. From there you can give it to your class or retreive it from the DI container. Will edit my example

Comment: Hey, I don't have a controller in my case. I just want to use this appseetings.json framework.

Comment: Hmm It should be possible to retreive it, but I don't know how it works with the .net core DI container. Let me check something

Comment: Please see my updated. It is a console class(no controller at all). How to get it from my `Call` class? I need code inside the method `GetHttpResponseMessageFromDeviceAndDataService`.

Comment: Do you have access to the HttpContext? In the context is an two possible instancec of the IServiceProvider `HttpContext.RequestServices` and `HttpContext.ApplicationServices`

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps not. My question actually can be as how to read a value in a console application. It is unrelated to `HttpContext`.

Comment: Hmm, then I guess not. I will try to find out if the DI option is still valid, if not I will modify my answer.

Comment: Do you create the Call class yourself? If so, is it possible to add an argument to it?

Comment: Somebody created it. I won't change it because it impacts many places. Perhaps I have to skip `Startup` class using FileIO to read json file?

Comment: If you don't want to modify it I think that would be the safest option.